# How to run javascript and test input on page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

I have datepicker and its working fine on change > table change depends on date, but the problem is when opening site for first time even datepicker has and display the current date, but no information shows in the table.
here code:

```js
$('#datepicker').change(function() {
    $.post('check_data.php', { dtpickerdate: $(this).val() }, function(response) {
        $('table').html(response);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can send your ajax request on page ready . please check below code:

```
$('#datepicker').change(function() {
  $.post('check_data.php', { dtpickerdate: $(this).val() }, function(response) {
    $('table').html(response); 
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.post('check_data.php', { dtpickerdate: $('#datepicker').val() }, function(response) {
    $('table').html(response); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `.change()` at the end of the block to trigger change event on opening site for the first time

```
$('#datepicker').change(function () {
    $.post('check_data.php', {
        dtpickerdate : $(this).val()
    }, function (response) {
        $('table').html(response);
    });
}).change();
```

---

EDIT: To populate datepicker with today's date and than trigger change use this

```
$('#datepicker').change(function () {
    $.post('check_data.php', {
        dtpickerdate : $(this).val()
    }, function (response) {
        $('table').html(response);
    });
});

$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date()).change();
```

Comment: Doesn't work, table display with no data, still have to change date from datepicker

Comment: @mate i have changed my answer so try it now

Comment: @mate no problem, glad I could help